# Connect to an upper level network's device

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, network-printer

I have the following local network:

[image]

My laptop is running windows 8.1.

When I connect to the network through cable (B) windows automatically detects the printer and I am all set to print, But when I connect through wireless (A) windows do not automatically detect either the printer or the network.

It seems that when I connect through wireless, there is a new local network created inside the original network, thus windows detects only one device in the current network, which is my laptop.

Is there a way to connect my laptop through wireless and print without the cable?

**Note that**

The rest of the network connections cannot change. This is an office network and the options I am given is these two: Either connect by cable or by wireless.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot:

Either the wireless network is a basic guest network with client isolation turned on **or** its more than a SOHO deployment and has a separate subnet and VLAN for wireless with no access to the printers VLAN.

This is an administrative decision. Talk to your superior.